# Replacing string with datetime Python

Tags: python, string, datetime, replace

I want to replace the following characters `tmp` from between the `/tmp/` to the current date from this string `/tmp/tmpy2919ufy`.
The output should be something like this `/20200615/tmpy2919ufy`
Could you please give some ideas as to how I might be able to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154151/10197418) - is that what you need? the current date as string is simply `datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')`, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with **datetime**

```py
from datetime import datetime

string = "/tmp/tmpy2919ufy"
replace_string = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

string = string.replace('tmp',replace_string,1)

#output >>> '/20200615/tmpy2919ufy'
```

Comment: you should note that this only changes the string, not the directory name. also, you do not need `regex` here. a simple `.replace('tmp', replace_string, 1)` will do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it definetly helps! :)