# Python - concatenate root directory name with all sub-folder names

Tags: python, rename

I have a root folder "topfolder". Inside that folder, I have multiple subfolders, "a", "b", "c".
I want to rename these subfolders so that they are concatenated with the root folder, such that they become "topfolder_a", "topfolder_b" and so on.
Is this relatively easy to do with Python?
I think I am almost there with this code but I can't get the last part.

```
test_directory = "./topfolder"
for child in os.listdir(test_directory):
    test_path = os.path.join(test_directory, child)
    if os.path.isdir(test_path):
        print(test_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `os.rename`:

```
import os

test_directory = "./topfolder"
for child in os.listdir(test_directory):
    test_path = os.path.join(test_directory, child)
    rename_path = os.path.join(test_directory, test_directory + "_" + child)
    if os.path.isdir(test_path):
        print(test_path, rename_path)
        os.rename(test_path, rename_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing dir name check this [change folder names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735312/how-to-change-folder-names-in-python). It's using os.rename

For the parent name, you can use split.

```
path = os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR)
path.split('/')[-1]
```

CURRENT_DIR is your current working dir in your case it's `child` is suppose.

Now you have a child and parent name both. You can figure concatenate them and rename them from the reference above.

Well, that's a long solution. but it explains how it'll work.
but rename takes full path so you can directly pass the path to rename

```
os.rename(CURRENT_DIR, test_directory + SEPERATOR + child)
```

here your SEPERATOR is '-' and you have the child in the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil

test_directory = "./topfolder"
for child in os.listdir(test_directory):
    test_path = os.path.join(test_directory, child)
    if os.path.isdir(test_path):
      shutil.move(test_path, os.path.join(test_directory, f"{test_directory}_{child}"))
```

In case you want to retain the orginal forder you can replace `move` with below

```
shutil.copytree(test_path, os.path.join(test_directory, f"{test_directory}_{child}"))
```